# Change GPIO pin mode to ALT with Python RPi.GPIO

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio

I usually use `RPi.GPIO` module like this to set up the GPIO pins:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
```

Is it possible to change mode of a pin to `ALT5` like I would do with `wiringpi`'s `gpio` tool :

```
> gpio -g mode 15 alt5 // sets GPIO 15 pin to ALT 5 mode
```

but with Python's `RPi.GPIO` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  As far as I am aware RPi.GPIO only supports modes INPUT and OUTPUT.  Modes ALT0, ALT1, ALT2, ALT3, ALT4, and ALT5 are not supported.

Comment: Ok! Is it me or the `RPi.GPIO` module documentation is really lacunar? No real exhaustive API, or maybe I looked at the wrong place? I'll do `gpio -g mode 15 alt5` before my Python script begins then...

Comment: A linked issue: I am now able to set RXd (GPIO 15) to RX1 (ie a 2nd serial port). *But* I don't have /dev/ttyAMA1 , I only have /dev/ttyAMA0. Do you know how to create that second serial port @joan ?

Comment: @Basj No, sorry, I don't know how to create /dev/ttyAMA1.  To what end though?  You'll still only have one serial link, just with a different name, as it uses the same gpios.  You'd need to have a compute module to get an additional serial port.

Comment: Because @joan  I want to use TX0 (ttyAMA0) for one thing (a 7segment display), and RX1 (ttyAMA1) for another thing (receive some MIDI IN!)... Therefore, I need 2 different half-ports  (for the 7segment display, I only need TX, and for MIDI IN, I only need RX) with 2 different baud setting...

Comment: @Basj You should be able to do that with /dev/ttyAMA0 without any fuss.  Open the port once for reading and again for writing.  You can certainly set different input/output baud rates from C

Comment: Have different baud rates for RX and TX on the same serial port? Really? This would be really great if possible. And with python `import serial` `port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=9600, timeout=2.0)` it doesn't seem possible because the port object is for both write and read

Comment: @Basj You can set independent baud rates via stty for the input and output side of the UART.  Unfortunately the UART itself only appears to use one baud rate so it appears to be a no go.

Comment: Hum... And is it the same if if I separate on two different ports TX => ttyAMA0   and RX => ttyAMA1 ?

Comment: @Basj I find the serial ports confusing.  I think TXD1/RXD1 are implemented with a different (mini) UART.  Unfortunately there are no kernel drivers for that UART.  pigpio supports [bit banging](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#bb_serial_read_open) serial ports.  The read side is quite straightforward and seems fairly solid up to 19k2 bps.